# Get release ID/number of all the CD pipelines under project

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to get the CD release name and ID/number of all the CD pipelines configured in specific branch. I have to export the details either using script or by any other way. Is it possible to get ID and name of CD pipelines automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you were trying to get the CD id/name in the pipeline tasks. You can get them directly by referring to the predefined [release variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch). `$(Release.DefinitionId)` and `$(Release.DefinitionName)`

The other way is to call [restful API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) via scripts.

```
 GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=5.1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have to generate the release notes we are currently doing manually. Also, I have to inegrate with Jira to get the tickets details. I'm trying the sample template available in the web, but not getting the actual result. We are using the guthub enterprise and unable to fetch the commits from that either in boards/work items. Without that how will I get the release notes. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: I donot really understand "unable to fetch the commits from that either in boards/work items". Is it in azure devops?